# Contradictory result when testing Linear independence using Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a set of vectors - (2,3,1) , (1,-1,2) and (7,3,8).
I want to find if its linearly dependent or independent.

Putting it as:
\begin{equation}
2a + b  + 7c = 0 \\
3a - b  + 3c = 0 \\
 a + 2b + 8c = 0
\end{equation}

If I use Gaussian elimination of equations to calculate row echelon form of the matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}
 2&1&7&0 \\ 
 3&-1&3&0 \\ 
 1&2&8&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

I get:

\begin{bmatrix}
 1&0&0&0 \\ 
 0&1&0&0 \\ 
 0&0&1&0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
which means a = b = c = 0

- So, as per
  [Determine if vectors are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412563/determine-if-vectors-are-linearly-independent)
  the vectors are linearly independent.
- But I know that they are linearly dependent, with a = 2, b = 3, c =
  -1

Why is there such a contradiction? did i do something procedurally wrong?

Note: I just want to understand the mistake in above procedure, dont want an alternate solution like using determinant etc (unless this procedure itself is totally wrong!)

Comment: I think you've made a mistake while putting it into row echelon form, I put your matrix into http://www.math.odu.edu/~bogacki/cgi-bin/lat.cgi?c=rref and it gives a different answer to yours which shows that they are indeed linearly dependent.

Comment: you did some mistakes in your process, the matrix is indeed linearly dependent

Comment: We can't really give you much advice here. The mistake is probably made during Gaussian elimination. Re-do the elimination, or if you want us to find the mistake, post the entire elimination, not only the final matrix...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that linear equations system and etc. mess. This just messes you, annoys you and distracts you away from more important things.

Just take your vectors, put them in matrix form (as all rows or all columns: it does *not* matter) and do Gauss. You can even choose to put in the upper row a vector which has $\;1\;$ as first entry, in case there is one...and there is in your case!:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2\\2&3&1\\7&3&8\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-2R_1,\,R_3-7R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&2\\0&5&-3\\0&10&-6\end{pmatrix}$$

and we can see at once that the third row equals twice the second one and we're done: the vectors are lin. dependent.

Comment: Yes, agreed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no contradiction: you reduced echelon form is wrong. Let me do it again:
\begin{align*}
&\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&7\\
3&-1&3\\
1&2&8
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&8\\
2&1&7\\
3&-1&3
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&8\\
0&-3&-9\\
0&-7&-21
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 8\\
0 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 1 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix},\\
&\text{whence the solutions: }\hspace{3.5em}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} =t\begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\-1\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

First note that
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 2&1&7&0 \\ 
 3&-1&3&0 \\ 
 1&2&8&0 \\
\end{array}\right]
\Rightarrow
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
 1&0&2&0 \\ 
 0&1&3&0 \\ 
 0&0&0&0 \\
\end{array}\right]
$$

**Using matrix equations**

> We have
>   $$
> a\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\
> 0\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> +b\begin{bmatrix}
> 0\\
> 1\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> +c\begin{bmatrix}
> 2\\
> 3\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> =\begin{bmatrix}
> 0\\
> 0\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   $$
> a\begin{bmatrix}
> 1\\
> 0\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> +b\begin{bmatrix}
> 0\\
> 1\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> =-c\begin{bmatrix}
> 2\\
> 3\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   $$
> \begin{bmatrix}
> a\\
> b\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> =-c\begin{bmatrix}
> 2\\
> 3\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> \neq\begin{bmatrix}
> 0\\
> 0\\
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   Therefore, the three vectors are linearly dependent.

**Using determinants**

> We have $$\begin{vmatrix}
>  2&1&7 \\ 
>  3&-1&3 \\ 
>  1&2&8\\
> \end{vmatrix}=
> \begin{vmatrix}
>  1&0&2 \\ 
>  0&1&3 \\ 
>  0&0&0 \\
> \end{vmatrix}=0$$
>   Therefore, the three vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: my vote is "not seen" but "recorded" as per MSE

Comment: I accept yours but unfortunately due to my "low reputation" the vote is recorded but not seen :(